# How do I convert this timestamp to another output by Oracle Developer?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a datetime formatted as such: `07/12/2021 16:00:00`.

I want to format it to be `12-JUL-21 16:00:00`.

I've tried a couple things using `strftime` with no luck. I know this should be easy but I am blanking....

Comment: Use `strptime` to convert the original string to a `datetime` object. Then use `strftime` to convert that back to a string. Ex: `datetime.strptime("07/12/2021 16:00:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S").strftime("%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S").upper()`

Comment: Thanks! I tried this ````datetime.strptime('07/12/2021 16:00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')````. It worked. How would I apply this to a column in a dataframe, say called ````DT_BILL_DT````?